# VBA finding "/" or "-" in a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba, slash, hyphenation

I want to write a code that deletes the rows that contain slash in a specific column. For example if in column H a slash appears in row 7, delete row 7. I was able to delete in cases where there were blank cells and in cases where there were words, but something with the slash is incorrect.

```vb
Rng.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="/"
Rng.Offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

I tried to use instead of "/" also "//" and "@/" but it didn't work.

I want to make an if statement so that if there is a number in a cell that contains numbers and "-", the cell value will be copied to another place. I could not find a way to incorporate the hyphen within the conditional sentence.

An example: 12345-6789.

Comment: Hi. Is there only slash in the said cell or is the slash in the said cell embended in a longer text?

Comment: For the second question you may need to do that in a loop or use a helper column.

Comment: The slash is within a series of numbers

Comment: What types of other values might be in the same column?  You'd likely need to loop over the values and check each cell - autofilter won't work for that.  Maybe look at using RegEx - https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub tester()
    With [A1].CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="=*/*"
        On Error Resume Next 'in case no matches
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: what about my question about the hyphen?